# How to assign a predefined array to length of zero

Tags: java

I have this block of code and if the main method calls this method and if the parameter is null, then an empty array should be assigned to data. How would I go about doing this?

```
// Private double array data

private double data[];

// Default constructor that creates a double array having a single element of 0.0

public Stat() {

    data = new double[0];

} // End of method

public class StatTester {

public void setData(double[] d) {

    if (d == null) {

        //where an empty array should be assigned to data

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of if condition

    else {

        double[] data = new double[d.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = d[c];

        } // End of for loop

        this.data = data;

    } // End of else condition

} // End of method

public static void main (String[] args) {

    double[] data1 = {50.0, 60.0};
    
    Stat stat1 = new Stat();
    
    data1 = null;
    stat1.setData(data1);
    System.out.println("stat1 data = " + stat1.toString());
    
}
```

Should output:
stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0]
stat1 data = []

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why `this.data = new double[0];` wouldn't work?

Comment: Why do you have a comment saying "// End of for loop" at the end of an if statement?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. It looks like different chunks of code hacked together. Also the comments saying exactly what the adjacent line of code says are not making it easier to read.

Comment: New double[0] creates an array with zero elements such that you cannot insert any elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not redeclare `data` in `setData`.
2. Return as soon as you assign an empty array to `data`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stat {
    private double data[];

    public Stat() {
        data = new double[0];
    }

    public void setData(double[] d) {
        if (d == null) {
            data = new double[0];
            return;
        }

        data = new double[d.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
            data[c] = d[c];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] data1 = { 50.0, 60.0 };
        Stat stat1 = new Stat();
        stat1.setData(data1);
        System.out.println("stat1 data = " + Arrays.toString(stat1.data));

        data1 = null;
        stat1.setData(data1);
        System.out.println("stat1 data = " + Arrays.toString(stat1.data));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
stat1 data = [50.0, 60.0]
stat1 data = []
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make an array with length of zero if you want to print an empty array like `[]` instead of printing `null` value:

```
if (d == null) {
   this.data = new double[0];
   return;
}
```

you can also do it in other way just assigning the `this.data` to d like below and it work correctly but it will print `null` instead of `[]`:

```
if (d == null) {
   this.data = d;
   return;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code, please check it again and up vote

Comment: How is "this.data" a local variable?

Comment: yes it will refer to the instance variable of your class: `private double data[];`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is.

To assign empty array (array of size 0) to data do same you do in constructor:

```
 data = new double[0];
```

However, since you've already did that in construction, just do nothing if `d == null`.

One thing confusing about your code is that you seem to have class `Stat` with field `data` and an inner class `StatTester` that refers to `data` from `Stat` via `this.data`, and does not declare it's own field `data`. And method `setData` is in `StatTester`, not `Stat` - so your code won't compile.

I'm assuming what you actually wanted is something this:
import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Stat {
    // Private double array data

    private double data[];

    // Default constructor that creates a double array having a single element of 0.0

    public Stat() {

        data = new double[0];

    } // End of method

    public void setData(double[] d) {

        if (d != null) {
            this.data = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);
        }

    } // End of method

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] data1 = { 50.0, 60.0 };

        Stat stat1 = new Stat();

        stat1.setData(null);
        System.out.println("stat1 data = " + stat1.toString()); // outputs empty array []

        stat1.setData(data1);
        System.out.println("stat1 data = " + stat1.toString()); // outputs [50.0, 60.0]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign an empty array to data simply do what you already have: `data = new double[0];`

However as Java is pass by value, where you indicate  you want to do this assignment will not work.  The reason is the variables data and d and separate. This can be confusing as when they both point to the same array, changes can be made to the array via either reference.  However what you are trying to do is not operate on the underlying array, but assign a new array back.

What you need to do is either change the return type of setData to double[] and assign it back or wrap data in another object/ array and then your assigment will work.